# JS - Running a jQuery function with a variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I need to run a function with a part dynamic variable in it's name.

**The function to run:**

```
$.element_gallery = function(state){}
```

**The code that's calling it:**

```
var name = "gallery";
window["$.element_"+name]('refresh');
```

This method seems to work with traditional Javascript functions but not with a jQuery function. Is there a way to run this without using `eval()` and without changing the function name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `window["$.foo"]` it's looking for a property on the window object that's called `$.foo`. However, if you're using a jQuery function it's stored in the jQuery (or `$`) property of the `window` object, so the actual location of the function you want is window.$["foo"]. Change your code to:

```
var name = "gallery";
window.$["element_"+name]('refresh');
```

Or, since you can access global variables without specifying `window.`, just:

```
var name = "gallery";
$[".element_"+name]('refresh');
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `window` with `$`

```
$["element_" + name]("refresh")
```

Comment: Yes, I think this will work as $ is an object, and this is how you can call a method or property of an object.